# How to define an iterator in a template?

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, iterator, erase

I'm trying to define an iterator to iterate my map to erase it (destructor)
I'm getting an error : incompatible iterator.

My destructor looks like this :

```
Consortium<S,T>::~Consortium()  
{  
    map<const S, Node<T>*>::iterator deleteIterator;  
    for (m_consortiumMap.begin() ; deleteIterator != m_consortiumMap.end() ; deleteIterator++)  
      m_consortiumMap.erase(deleteIterator);  
}
```

I create like this :

```
Consortium<string, Vehicle*> check;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Need more info - where have you defined your iterator, for example

Comment: I guess you need a `typename`.

Comment: just curious why aren't you using map::clear(), which does the same thing and more elegant...

Comment: If you can use C++0x features, you could just use `auto`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to clear a `std::map` in a destructor at all. But you may want to do something about stored pointers (e.g `Vehicles` that are allocated dynamically and owned by `Consortium`.

Comment: 1) You need `typename`, since `T` is a dependent type. 2) You never assign `deleteIterator`. 3) Just use `clear()`. 4) Don't do anything, it'll clear automatically. 5) Everything should happen automatically, so use a smart pointer if those should be deleted.

Comment: Solved. using clear() instead solved it, thanks all.

Comment: @Roy: What's the point in calling `clear()` in a destructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that `map<const S, Node<T>*>::iterator` is a so-called *dependent name*: it is depends on the template arguments and, in theory, there could be a specialization of `std::map` for some `S`, `T` which defines `iterator` to be a static data member, the name of a member function or whatever. What it is, the compiler only finds out when instantiating your template. So you have to help the compiler by explaining to it that `iterator` is the name of a type. (Silly, I know, but compilers really are that stupid). You do it by putting a `typename` in front of it:

```
typename map<const S, Node<T>*>::iterator deleteIterator;
```

However, what you're actually doing is wrong. You don't need to manually delete the elements your map hosts. But.

You are using naked, dumb pointers as the map's referred type. Who owns these objects? Who is responsible for deleting them? You might have to go through your map and (instead of removing the pointers) delete the objects referred to by these pointers. But that's error prone, and still leaves open questions regarding the object's lifetime. (Like: Who takes responsibility for objects removed from the map?)
I strongly suggest you follow [fnieto's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750085/how-to-define-an-iterator-in-a-template/3750168#3750168) and use a smart pointer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map<const S, shared_ptr<Node<T> > >` instead.